# JavaからElasticSearchに接続できない

Tags: spring, java8, elasticsearch, junit

環境は
Spring4.2
SpringDataElasticsearch
Java1.8
です。

ESサーバーはAWS/Redhat7で、localhostの9200をポートフォワードして接続しています。
※xinetdやfirewall, SELinux, セキュリティーグループも確認しましたが、直接接続がなぜかできないため、ポートフォワードしました。

接続確認として、JUnitでテストしています。

http://localhost:9200/ で接続も確認しました。

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:esearch.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages={"com.aaa.repository"})
public class EsConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    private static final String ESEARCH_PORT = "esearch.port";
    private static final String ESEARCH_HOST = "esearch.host";

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception{
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception{
        return new TransportClient()
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200));
    }
}
```

TESTCASE

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={EsConfig.class})
public class EsRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Test
    public void test_FIND() throws Exception {
        Iterable<Test> test = testRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

JUnitエラー

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:305)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.count(AbstractClient.java:379)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.count(TransportClient.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.count.CountRequestBuilder.doExecute(CountRequestBuilder.java:146)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.doCount(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:450)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.count(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.count(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.findAll(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at jp.gvs.api.es.test.EsRepositoryTest.test_FIND(EsRepositoryTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

スタックトレース

```
03:03:26.518 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport - [Hub] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][name][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]], disconnecting...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[localhost/127.0.0.1:9200]][cluster:monitor/nodes/info] request_id [0] timed out after [5002ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:529) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

設定に不備があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

TransportClient が利用するポートは、9300 であるような気がします。

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html

Elasticsearch は、 http 用(9200)と Transport 用(9300)の2つの 通信ポートを用意していたはず。

Comment: あら、本当だ。9300でないとダメですね。

Comment: 9300で接続テストを行いましたが、結果的にはバージョンの相違で接続できなかったようでした。1.7系に再インストールしたところ、接続を確認できましたが、上記環境バージョンで、ElasticSearch2.xに接続することは現状できないのでしょうか？

Comment: @omarun 基本的に、 Client とサーバーの Elasticsearch のバージョンは、一致させるべきかと思います。ソースは、ちょっとぱっとは出てきませんが。。

Comment: @omarun BTW, Elasticsearch が正式名称なはずです。(ElasticSearchではなく)